# You are not authorized to access that database lotus notes client

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have registered the new user in Domino Admin, the user named TestUser with the default ACL level that is set to editor and enabled the userid file creation and the user was registered successfully and id file was created successfully. When I try to login the TestUser with user id file in lotus notes client I am not able access the contacts/email/meetings forms of the TestUser and I am not able to open the user itself. I am getting "You are not authorized to access that database" error in lotus notes client. How can i resolve this error ? Whenever I am registered new user and trying to login into lotus notes client the same issue occurred.

Comment: Sorry, but there seems to be a severe misconfiguration on your site: normally every user automatically can access his own mailfile without any needed change from the domino admin. Please ask a specialist to check your environment as this is NOT normal behaviour and analysing this error via serverfault is out of scope here.

Comment: Do you use the same machine to test the ID's ?

Comment: @umeli Yes, I have used the same machine.

Comment: It could be that one or more local databases are protected.. Have you tested it with a clean notes client install